# Body background image slide transition instead of fade

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three different images that I have for the body and I have a javascript function that changes the class in between as such

```
function bgchange()
    {
        document.body.className = 'intro2';
        setTimeout(bgchange2, 3000);
    }
```

and the three classes that each has a different background looks like this

```
.intro {
background: url('../img/home-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-webkit-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms; 
-moz-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
-o-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
}

    .intro2 {
background: url('../img/home-bg2.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-webkit-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms; 
-moz-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
-o-transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
transition: background 300ms ease-in 200ms;
}
```

This gives me a fade transition but instead of a fade transition I want a slide up effect while the new class img appears underneath, I tried everything from css background-position to using javascript but I couldn't figure it out, any help?

Comment: You will have to use animation instead of transition.

Comment: Do you have to use background or can you use images inside a div!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I got what you want but if I understood right this could be an option!

```js
var e = 0;
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i){
    images[i].style.top = (i * 100) +'%';
}
setInterval(function(){
    e++;
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i){
      var image = images[i % images.length];  
      console.log(image.style.top);
      image.style.zIndex = '999';
      relocate(image, -((e % images.length) * 100)+'%', 99);
    } 
    console.log('done='+e);
}, 2500)

function relocate(image, offset, z){
  image.style.webkitTransform = 'translateY('+offset+')';
  image.style.mozTransform = 'translateY('+offset+')';
  image.style.transform = 'translateY('+offset+')';
  
  image.style.zIndex = 0;
}
```

```css
#container{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
  
    
    background: #FFFFFF;  
    overflow: hidden;
    
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#content{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
img{
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  
    -webkit-transition: transform 1.5s ease-in 200ms; 
       -moz-transition: transform 1.5s ease-in 200ms;
         -o-transition: transform 1.5s ease-in 200ms;
            transition: transform 1.5s ease-in 200ms;   
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <img src= 'http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/4f133d5a-f35e-469a-89d1-71324412246b/9e064c73-1ca4-47ce-a472-606aad942887.jpg'/>

  <img src= 'http://www.yosemitepark.com/Images/home-img-02.jpg'/>
  <img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXOTXgKi8EnXyySIBQeHbDJfYdhxN3_PqtsDl3WgQHfqJXb7_VyQ'/>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: This would have been perfect if it kept sliding down and the first image would have appeared instead of scrolling back up

Comment: Hey man we are here to help you, not to do things for you. Try something, then if you have trouble getting it done ask for help. But don't say this would have been perfect ... It is done, does not need much work to make it work the way you wanted. You just have to think a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

We are here to help you, not to do things for you. That's is more than perfect, think a little bit it only need a little tweak!